# Creating 16 lists from 5?

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I have 5 parameters with 16 entries each that i need to normalize

```
Life_expectancy = [59.61,45.00,51.30,70.48,75.77,74.87,73.12,81.30,78.51,80.15,80.09,80.24,80.99,81.43,80.67,67.62]
Top_10_income = [23.21,47.67,38.23,26.58,32.30,29.98,42.93,28.80,29.85,27.23,28.49,22.07,24.79,25.40,22.18,27.81,31.68]
Infant_mortality = [74.30,73.10,82.60,19.60,13.30,13.70,14.50,3.60,6.30,3.50,4.40,3.50,4.90,4.20,2.40,4.90,10.00]
Military_spend = [4.44,0.09,1.07,1.86,0.76,1.95,1.43,6.77,4.72,0.60,2.59,1.31,1.42,1.86,1.27,1.13,3.87]
School_years = [0.40,3.40,4.10,5.30,10.10,6.40,7.20,12.50,13.70,11.50,13.00,12.00,14.20,11.50,12.80,12.30,12.90]

list of parameters = [Life_expectancy,Top_10_income,Infant_mortality,Military_spend,School_years]
```

I need help with a function that i can write to normalize the values within the nested list (life expectancy etc) using min max normalization

I now need the first entries from each of the 5 lists to form 16 different lists with 5 entries each which i will then use to find the manhattan distance between the 15 countries and one of those countries for which i need to predict a particlaur inidcator using 3 nearest neighbour and weighted KNN

Could someone throw in some ideas about how i could flip 5 lists with 16 entries each to get 16 lists with 5 enntires each

Wondering if reading in the CSV with the data as a dataframe will be simpler??

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you show a minimal reproducible snippet. Assuming your 5 params are a nested list `params`, `list(zip(*params))` will transpose rows to cols.

Comment: please check updated post ,

Answer (score 1):

```
your_data = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], 
              # etc., 5 sublists total
            ]

your_new_data = list(zip(*your_data))
```